# How to build a timeline control from scratch, the math, looks, feel... (implementing in C++ and ATL/WTL)

Tags: math, graphics, open-source, timeline

I have a pet project called DebugView++ (https://github.com/CobaltFusion/DebugViewPP)

This is a logviewing tool and I want to add a timeline-view to it.

This is what I have so far:

[image: this is what I have so far]

Basically, I can draw what ever I want, that part is ok. I have a scale, a cursor, a timeline and 'flags' or artifacts as I call them on the timeline.

What I want to do I to make it 'infinitely' zoomable, so I can zoom out to 1000px == 1 day or 1 year and zoom in to 1000px == 1 microsecond.

The problem is, how to do the math on scaling artifacts.

- what is the best way to round when the 'time' does not match an 'exact' pixel.
- at some level, the artifacts start piling up / overlapping and I will have to display an 'there is more here if you zoom in' kind of artifact.
- I want to 'zoom' in to the current cursor

I could really use some help on how to set this up, I got a real headache from 
the calculations that just do not 'work' for all edge cases, in the sense that the result is not pleasing to look at when:

- the data set is smaller then the current view size
- the granularity of the data is arbitrary, sometimes there is a data-point, then nothing for an hour and then 100th's of data-points

I have very little experience in graphics rendering; 
Does anyone have tips on how to 'think' about the rendering of such a timeline. To me it sounds like UI people have solved this (and much more complex) so I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Nico>
I have not solved the scaling, the math for the zooming/scaling/positioning is my main problem. first of all, I'm not sure whether to use discrete math or floating point math.

I have a few inputs:

- the data to display, an set of arbitrary events at fixed time-points.
- the datapoint with the earliest timepoint is the beginning of the range.
- the datapoint with the latest timepoint is the end of the range.
- the set can grow, and typically is growing as the datapoints are derived from a logfile
- the current range of the view
- the position of the cursor in the view
- the scrollwheel (affects the zoomfactor)

and outputs:

- the scale (not the zoom-factor): the numbers on the timeline
- the datapoints (I call them artifacts) drawn in the view

suppose the current dataset is (in seconds)

```
1:  red flag
3:  red flag
5:  red flag
7:  red flag
10: red flag
```

From that I start:

```
datarange = 1 to 10 seconds.
viewXmin = 0px
viewXmax = 1000px
scalefactor = 1.0 

unitsToPixels = 1000px / (size(datarange)) = 100px
unitsToPixels = 1000px / 9 = 111.111111111px
```

pos to draw flag = unitsToPixels * timeInSeconds

So here there is already some inaccuracy 111.111111111px, some precision has been lost there. I really want to do this in nanoseconds (or better), so:

```
unitsToPixels = 1000px / 9e-9) = 1.111111111e-7px

pos to draw flag = unitsToPixels * timeInSeconds
pos to draw flag = 1.111111111e-7px* 5e-9 = 555.555555px.
```

I'm not sure where to go from here...
Is this ok?

Also its about answering design questions I don't know the answer too:

- should the content of a timeline change if you resize the window or does the the way it is displayed change? do you display more of the timeline or the same piece but spread over more pixels?
- given N pixels should the amount of major-ticks be odd or even?
- odd seems a good choice so there is always a major tick at the beginning and end of the view, but what to do when the major tick is exactly at both the first and the last pixel of the view; then you wouldn't be able to see it clearly, so how to handle the edge case.
- how to display numbers on the scale with 'enough' precision? example: 850.000us, 950.000us, 1.050ms is now displayed on a scale. 850.000us not needed because the precision is 'just not there', but I can't really tell that from the number itself.

The list goes on...

Then another thing: aside from it being pixel-precise it also quite ugly, basically I want it do look nice and be user friendly, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.. any ui designers got any tips?

Meowgoesthedog> 
Its not about the GDI that part is working fine.

-Jan.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're having trouble with? Have you solved the scaling and just want to cluster the artifacts?

Comment: If you're worried about sub-pixel rounding, you could use GDI+ with antialiasing.

Comment: If have updated the question

Comment: My point is, GDI doesn't have the antialiasing functionality you need to overcome the sub-pixel problem.

Comment: meowgoesthedog: I understand, but this is not my problem, the way I see it, I'm not going to rely on sub-pixels to be drawn, just making the calculations for the real pixels is complicated enough

Comment: I've been rehashing this and central question I'm faced with now: Should the content of a timeline change if you resize the window _or_ does the the _way_ it is displayed change? I think it the second makes more sense if you compare it to lets say 'an office or paint application', the image does not change/scale to the window size... you get more canvas... not a rescaled image. Then again, this is not an editor, its a viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer my own question.

So first of all.

1) what is the best way to round when the 'time' does not match an 'exact' pixel.

just round down, if this is the case, then the current view resolution is not good enough to render an accurate representation, so it really does not matter.

2) at some level, the artifacts start piling up / overlapping and I will have to display an 'there is more here if you zoom in' kind of artifact.

This is just a design decision, artifact that render within N pixels of eachother will overlap. You have to detect this and render a different artifact in this case.
This will require processing the artifacts twice before rendering in case they are not sorted. (otherwise you won't know if not-yet-processed artifact will overlap)

3) I want to 'zoom' in to the current cursor

if center-zoom is done by adjusting the pixels-per-timeunit value.
then 'cursor-zoom' is is done adjusting the pixels-per-timeunit value AND an timeunit-offset

... to be continued